# How to have the same keyboard shortcuts everywhere

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any solution to have the same shortcuts to do the same thing on different programs. For example in VLC I press `CTRL+UP` and `CTRL+DOWN` to change volume, but on my TV card application I have to press `+` and `-`.

I know I can change settings to one of them to make key match, but I was wondering if there is some kind of application that does that in a systematic way for several different applications, without the need of long and boring manual configuration.

(I am using Windows)

Comment: There are many versions of Windows. Knowing which one you are using may be helpful in someone answering your question. Also, what have you attempted or researched so far?

Comment: I am using windows 7 and Windows 8, so as well saying windows, since I don't think someone will come up with a solution that works on Vista or XP but not on 7 and 8 :P
If I am asking is because I didn't find anything, and I do not think I missed any obvious solution.

Comment: Just because you posted a question here doesn't mean you did any research. Many people ask before looking for themselves. We are good, but we aren't mind readers. Details are very helpful in this community to avoid the "*I already tried that*" and "*That doesn't apply to my OS*" responses to answers. With that being said, I doubt there is a solution as keyboard shortcut functionality is programmed into the specific applications, if at all, and is not likely to be standardized.